# Most efficient way to separate rows into groups populate a main ID field to link the sub groups in a T-SQL in a large dataset

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a data file that I need to format correctly in order to use. It is quite a large file (roughly 3.4 million rows).

The issue is the format the file I am being sent is in a totally different format to how I need to use the file. I have no say over the format of the file as it is from an external source.

Source file:

```
100000001 567890 123456ZZZ 0 Description line
100000001 X999999999999    1
100000001 Y999999999999    1
100000001 Z999999999999    1
100000001 123456789        2
100000001 234567890        2

100000001 567890 123456YYY 0 Description line
100000001 X999999999999    1
100000001 Y999999999999    1
100000001 Z999999999999    1
100000001 123456789        2
100000001 234567890        2

100000002 678901 123456ZZZ 0 Description line
100000002 Y999999999999    1
100000002 Z999999999999    1
100000002 123456789        2
```

The issue is with the exception of the first 9 characters which determines the main record data the data is fixed widths but these change depending on the type which is a number 0-2.

So in this case the data contains 3 records, consisting of two groups of data which have different formats but those other lines do not have any of the reference information on them (123456ZZZ, 123456YYY).

My plan was to split the data into three separate tables, one for the main records (type 0), one for the 2nd group (type 1) and one for the final group (type 2).

To do this however I would need to populate the data tables for type 1 and type 2 with the two blocks of information from the main record.

- 567890
- 123456
- YYY

This would then result in the following tables.

### Table 1 - Main Records (Type 0)

```
| ID | Ref       | Model  | Range  | Variant | Description      |
|----|-----------|--------|--------|---------|------------------|
| 01 | 100000001 | 567890 | 123456 | ZZZ     | Description line |
| 02 | 100000001 | 567890 | 123456 | YYY     | Description line |
| 03 | 100000002 | 678901 | 123456 | ZZZ     | Description line |
```

### Table 2 - Group 1 (Type 1)

```
| Ref       | ID | Part          |
|-----------|----|---------------|
| 100000001 | 01 | X999999999999 |
| 100000001 | 01 | Y999999999999 |
| 100000001 | 01 | Z999999999999 |
| 100000001 | 02 | X999999999999 |
| 100000001 | 02 | Y999999999999 |
| 100000001 | 02 | Z999999999999 |
| 100000001 | 02 | Y999999999999 |
| 100000001 | 03 | Z999999999999 |
```

### Table 2 - Group 2 (Type 2)

```
| Ref       | ID | Operation |
|-----------|----|-----------|
| 100000001 | 01 | 123456789 |
| 100000001 | 01 | 234567890 |
| 100000001 | 02 | 123456789 |
| 100000001 | 02 | 234567890 |
| 100000001 | 03 | 123456789 |
```

The ID column in table 2 and 3 being used to link to the main record to use a join on the final select to bring back these rows as well when the relevant search to find the main record.

The issue I am having is so far the best way to do this I have managed to find is using a CURSOR but obviously this is a very bad way of doing this as there are a lot of records and just the test data set of a few thousand rows is taking a while to run so 3.4 mil rows will take well in excess of a day to complete.

My knowledge of T-SQL for this type of manipulation is quite limited and as I found on another issue with MySQL often the answers you find when doing a search might not be the best way of doing something (as I have found with the CURSOR) so thought I would seek some advice.

Comment: This doesn't sound like something you want to do in the database. Maybe you could just create a script or program that reads the file and creates 3 separate files based on your needs? Don't know enough about SSIS that I could say if that could be used or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the previous suggestion of using some inserts the solution I have ended up using which has taken the time to run from a CURSOR of about 16 days down to just under 1 hour was a series of INSERT statements in a WHILE loop.

```
DECLARE @counter int

SELECT @counter = COUNT(ID) FROM import_table

DECLARE @i int = 1


DECLARE @ID int, @type int

WHILE (@i <= @counter)
BEGIN

IF ((SELECT type FROM import_table WHERE ID = @i) = 0)
BEGIN

-- Set ID for main record
SELECT @ID = ID FROM import_table WHERE ID = @i

-- Import data rows into main table
INSERT INTO data_main (...)
SELECT (...)
FROM import_table
WHERE pckID = @i

END


IF ((SELECT type FROM import_table WHERE ID = @i) = 1)
BEGIN

-- Import data rows into main table
INSERT INTO data_group_1  (..., mainID)
SELECT (..., @ID)
FROM import_table
WHERE pckID = @i

END

IF ((SELECT type FROM import_table WHERE ID = @i) = 2)
BEGIN

-- Import data rows into main table
INSERT INTO data_group_2 (..., mainID)
SELECT (..., @ID)
FROM import_table
WHERE pckID = @i

END

SET @i = @i + 1

END
```

While it may not be the most efficient way and I certainly agree that a program or looking into the SSIS functions would be the best route forwards at the moment this is certainly more efficient in respect of time than using the CURSOR to loop through all the records.

The only requirement is that I have to make sure that the import_table has its AI ID value reset to 1 each time which I will put as part of the being of the stored proc.

In essence this set of code uses a counter value to count the total number of rows in the import table, where the ID beginning at 1 will link nicely to an incrementing counter.

Then the next part of the selection is a WHILE loop using a simple @i integer to increase this value each time.

Every time a record that has its type as 0 the @ID value is set to this records ID value and that data is inserted using an INSERT statement.

If the type field is 1 or 2 then the @ID value is not changed but instead used to populate the mainID column of the Group 1 or Group 2 tables which run an INSERT statement using that data.

To get around the issue with the field lengths being different on each type with the exception of the REF column and TYPE column for the import_table I have set 5 columns.

1. ID
2. Ref
3. ContentA
4. Type
5. ContentB

Then in each of the insert statements the ID field is auto incremented, the Ref comes directly from that field in the main data as does type.

For the other fields I am using a set of SUBSTRING lookups to extract the data at the points the original specification lists.

```
, Ref
, SUBSTRING(ContentA,2,5)
, SUBSTRING(ContentA,6,2)
, SUBSTRING(ContentB,1,10)
, SUBSTRING(ContentA,11,5)
```

Again I am sure that there is probably a better way of doing this by writing a program in C# or using SSIS.

In the interim however this solution is certainly a more efficient way of looping through the records than using a CURSOR.

Hopefully this makes sense and will prove useful to somebody else who is trying to extract data from one source into several tables using purely a SQL Stored Proc without using SSIS.

Answer (score 1):

Building a program in C# or some other language would be the best way to do it, that is what I am cuurently doing. One way you could do this without coding is to create a dummy table with an index on the Ref column it's not mandatory but makes the solution faster. Then after the whole file is inserted into the table you could a couple of INSERT statements with a select to put the data into the correct tables. After that truncate the dummy table so it will be ready for the next file coming in. If you use SQL Server Job Agent you could automate this to it would be completely hands-off. This is what previously worked for me and I couldn't find a better way. The best solution is to use SSIS by having a script run to break up the file and make several smaller files then load them into the correct tables. SSIS would be a more permanent solution.

Comment: Writing a program did seem like one of the options.

Comment: Using your suggestions of an INSERT I have managed to come up with a solution that has certainly helped speed up the process. Fortunately this is something that only needs to be done once a month so I can afford to set a job running at 2AM that will take an hour to populate the tables.